# How to incorporate a changing variable into a text Msgbox in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, vbe

I am currently trying to make a simple VBA program that would multiply two numbers together and then prompt a message box that says "The value of `(variable1)` and `(variable 2)` is `(The answer)`.

Here is my current attempt that isn't perfect:

```
 MsgBox prompt:=intmlt, Title:="The Value of " & intFirstNum & intSecondNum
```

The two big issues I have is how to you put a space inbetween the `intFirstNum` and `intSecondNum`? and How do you add an is to the end of that prompt?

Comment: `"The Value of " & intFirstNum & " and " & intSecondNum & " is "`

Comment: THANK YOU! that worked perfectly. I was inverting the & and " at one point

Answer (score 0):

*It  should be*

***`"The Value of " & intFirstNum & " and " & intSecondNum & " is "`***

***Per @ScottHoltzman***